# create the Span element dynamically

Tags: javascript, web

Hello I am looking for some working code to create span elements.

My text is simple each word is seperated by space.

I need to create span as follow so that I can lift the code quickly. As mention below each word has unique id as W1, W2, etc.

```
<p>
  <!-- I need to create span as follow so that -->
  <span id="W1">I</span>  
  <span id="W2">need</span>  
  <span id="W3">to/span>  
  <span id="W4">create</span>  
  <span id="W5">span</span>  
  <span id="W6">as</span>  
  <span id="W7">follow</span>  
  <span id="W8">so</span>  
  <span id="W9">that</span> 
</p>
```

Thanks.

I have MS expression web and vb studio, any tool I can keep locally and keep creating.

[I see this link on web doing something.](http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/Javascript/Javascript-DOM/Create-Span-Using-Document-createElement/Default.aspx)

Comment: Smells like a homework...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
<body>
    <p>
    </p>
</body>
```

Js

```
<script>
    var sString = "asdf sadfasd f sdfasd fasdfasdfasdf";
    var aString = sString.split(' ');

    for (var i=0;i<aString.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += '<span class="w' + i + '">' + aString[i] + '</span>'
    }
</script>
```

And always post your code, even if it seems to you foolish and wrong :)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this code. I was doing this manually using some editor and putting code inside my xhtml file. I need something so that I can see generated HTML code as I showed in the example. Any help will help.

Comment: Quick and dirty:  `prompt("Copy n paste this", document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML);` at the end of the above script.

Comment: If you user firefox for browsing you can install firebug plugin, really awesome tool for a web developer

Answer (score 1):

```
// You either have a string 
var mysentence = "I need to do my homework";

// or a paragraph
<p id="words">I need to do my homework</p>
// get sentence
var mysentence = document.getElementById('words');


function spanify(sentence) {
  var arrayOfStrings = sentence.split(" "), newString = "";
    for (var i=0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
        newString += "<span id='W" + i + "'>" + arrayOfStrings[i] + "</span>";
        }
        return newString;
    }

// spanify the sentence
spanify(mysentence);
```